# What does this message mean?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I was working on tags (between answers) and when I wanted to suggest a tag synonym I got this message:

[image]

What does it mean?

Comment: Related:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121457/version-specific-tag-validation-on-tag-synonym-page

Comment: I have added the tag, does not really fix the issue.

Comment: @Kortuk - Yes, I saw it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, there are tags for code libraries and software development platforms. For instance, there's a [jquery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag. In many cases, it is redundant to list tag synonyms for each release of a library update, so the developers put in place validation to prevent people from creating synonyms like [jquery1.6](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.6) and [jquery1.7](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.7).

Since this site runs on the same engine, the system thinks you're creating a version-specific tag, and only diamond moderators can create version specific tag synonyms. In short, you're not doing anything wrong, you're just getting caught up in some of the system safeguards.